# How do I avoid joining multiple times when using union all statement?

Tags: postgresql

I was working on a query where I hit a point:

```
SELECT tpd.timestamp::Date,'Mon' AS Label,
       count(tpd.aggregated)
FROM tap.deving AS tpd INNER JOIN
  (select DATE_TRUNC('week', timestamp),  MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
   from tap.deving
   group by DATE_TRUNC('week', timestamp)
  ) b
on tpd.timestamp = b.max_timestamp 
left JOIN ca.hardware AS ch ON tpd.dev = ch.name
left JOIN ca.sites AS css ON css.id = ch.id
WHERE (tpd.aggregated=TRUE)
  AND (css.country='USA') and (tpd.timestamp::date=now()::Date - interval '1 day') group by tpd.timestamp
UNION ALL
SELECT tpd.timestamp::date,'Tap but not' AS Label,
       count(tpd.tap)
FROM tap.deving AS tpd INNER JOIN
  (select DATE_TRUNC('week', timestamp),  MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
   from tap.deving
   group by DATE_TRUNC('week', timestamp)
  ) b
on tpd.timestamp = b.max_timestamp 
left JOIN ca.hardware AS ch ON tpd.dev = ch.name
left JOIN ca.sites AS css ON css.id = ch.id
WHERE (tpd.tap=true)
  AND (tpd.aggregated=false) and (tpd.needs_to_be=true)
  AND (css.country='USA')  and (tpd.timestamp::date=now()::Date - interval '1 day') group by tpd.timestamp
```

I wrote this query with the help of many SO posts and it has gone quite messy and super slow. I could not get my head on how to optimize this query.

Comment: Why you are not using OR condition instead of union all.

Comment: How can I avoid joining twice by adding OR? @shivam

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this query.

```
 SELECT tpd.timestamp::Date,CASE tpd.aggregated
      WHEN false THEN 'Tap but not'
      WHEN true THEN 'Mon' as Label,
       count(tpd.aggregated)
FROM tap.deving AS tpd INNER JOIN
  (select DATE_TRUNC('week', timestamp),  MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
   from tap.deving
   group by DATE_TRUNC('week', timestamp)
  ) b
on tpd.timestamp = b.max_timestamp 
left JOIN ca.hardware AS ch ON tpd.dev = ch.name
left JOIN ca.sites AS css ON css.id = ch.id
WHERE ((tpd.aggregated=TRUE)  or ((tpd.tap=true)  AND (tpd.aggregated=false) and (tpd.needs_to_be=true)))
  AND (css.country='USA') and (tpd.timestamp::date=now()::Date - interval '1 day') group by tpd.timestamp;
```

Comment: you ignored the second condition!

Comment: As in your query , some where clause are same  with second query.   I merged your 2nd query   with 1st query.

Comment: I believe 2 conditions in OR  "((tpd.aggregated=TRUE)  or ((tpd.tap=true)  AND (tpd.aggregated=false) and (tpd.needs_to_be=true))"   are the difference in between your second query and first query

Comment: you please test it , then let me know whether it is working or not

Comment: Your query combines two categories 'Mon' and 'Tap but not'.

Comment: just wait for some min..updating the answer.